# Django doesn't recognize Gensim

Tags: python, django, numpy, pycharm, gensim

I'm using Python, Django, IDE PyCharm. I imported Gensim for my project, however, seems like Django does not recognize it. Here are my versions: **gensim-3.6.0 numpy-1.15.4 scipy-1.1.0 python 3.7.1**

The following error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/sma-capstone-2018/sma_core/brinfluence/lib/doc2vec.py", line 4, in <module>
    import gensim
  File "C:\Users\Me\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Me\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\parsing\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .preprocessing import (remove_stopwords, strip_punctuation, strip_punctuation2,  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Me\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\parsing\preprocessing.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gensim import utils
  File "C:\Users\Me\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 40, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "C:\Users\Me\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "C:\Users\Me\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csr.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: is your path set correctly? if you recently installed gensim, maybe the path variable has not been updated yet. Therefore, a restart of your shell or of the whole windows machine might bring an improvement.

Comment: are you using a virtualenv? did you install it using command line or pycharm?

Comment: @PeterGrundner I did, but it didn't help

Comment: @Incognos using pycharm terminal

Comment: did you use a virtualenv? if so, please do a `pip list` and show the results of your virtualenv

Comment: actually, it looks like it cannot find `.csr` not `gensim`

Comment: @Incognos
beautifulsoup4  4.6.3
boto            2.49.0
boto3           1.9.57
botocore        1.12.57
bs4             0.0.1
bz2file         0.98
certifi         2018.10.15
chardet         3.0.4
docutils        0.14
emoji           0.5.1
gensim          3.6.0
idna            2.7
jmespath        0.9.3
nltk            3.4
numpy           1.15.4
pip             10.0.1
python-dateutil 2.7.5
requests        2.20.1
s3transfer      0.1.13
scipy           1.1.0
setuptools      39.1.0
singledispatch  3.4.0.3
six             1.11.0
smart-open      1.7.1
urllib3         1.24.1